# C: Do I have to initialize arrays used within a function?

Tags: arrays, c, initialization

While debugging my program I noticed that some elements of my 2D-array contain nonzero values.

```
float Ak[2][2];
Ak[0][0] = 1;
Ak[1][1] = 1;
```

When I run this code `Ak[0][0]` and `Ak[1][1]` are 1 as expected but `Ak[0][1]` was 1.081 which I actually expected to be 0.

That's probably due to the fact that arrays aren't implicitly initialized. But is this always the case? Do I always have to initialize my arrays when I want specific behavior or are there some cases where the compiler does this automatically? Is it compiler dependent?

And the almost most important question: Where is this behavior specified? (I need a citation for my Thesis)

Comment: Local variables don't have any default initialization.  They're about as likely to start out containing 0 as any other seemingly random value.  This applies both to arrays and to ordinary variables.  You can read a summary of the initialization rules for different classes of variables  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51329671/difference-between-static-global-variable-and-non-static-global-variable-in-c).

Comment: Local non-static variables are uninitialized.  Local static variables are implicitly initialized to zero, just as non-local variables are.

Answer (score 4):

Any variable (not just arrays) defined locally that isn't `static`, or more formally those with *automatic storage duration*, are not implicitly initialized.  Those defined at file scope or with `static`, i.e. those with *static storage duration*, are implicitly initialized to 0 or NULL.

This is spelled out in section 6.7.9p10 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> If  an  object  that  has  automatic  storage  duration  is  not
> initialized  explicitly,  its  value  is indeterminate.   If  an
> object  that  has  static  or  thread  storage  duration  is  not
> initialized explicitly, then:
>
> - if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
> - if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
> - if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules,and any padding is initialized to zero bits;
> - if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules, and any padding is initialized
>   to zero bits;

And of course, just because an uninitialized variable happens to be 0 doesn't mean it doesn't contain garbage.

Comment: Also, just because it happens to be 0 does not mean it is 0! *Indeterminate* means it could be 3 even if it was seen to be 0.

Answer (score 1):

Variables that have automatic storage duration (variables declared in a block scope) are not initialized implicitly.

Variables that have static storage duration (variables declared in a file scope or that have the specifier static) if not initialized explicitly initialized implicitly (for arithmetic types they are zero-initialized, or for pointer types they are initialized as null pointers).

It seems you declared your array within a function

```
float Ak[2][2];
Ak[0][0] = 1;
Ak[1][1] = 1;
```

So its elements are not initialized implicitly.

You could write for example

```
float Ak[2][2] =
{
    [0][0] = 1.0f, [1][1] = 1.0f 
};
```

In this case all elements of the array will be initialized. Elements that do not have an explicit initializer will be zero-initialized.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    float Ak[2][2] =
    {
        [0][0] = 1.0f, [1][1] = 1.0f 
    };

    printf( "Ak[0][0] = %f, Ak[0][1] %f, Ak[1][1] = %f\n", 
             Ak[0][0], Ak[0][1], Ak[1][1] );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Ak[0][0] = 1.000000, Ak[0][1] 0.000000, Ak[1][1] = 1.000000
```

Alternatively you could initialize your array also the following way

```
float Ak[2][2] =
{
    [0] = { [0] = 1.0f }, [1] = { [1] = 1.0f } 
};
```