# Input multiple integer values and print them in C

Tags: c, gcc, input, compilation, output

I'm new to C language. Here's the code I used to get input for a and b and print them. But I did not get the values I entered via the terminal can you explain why I got different values for a and b?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a,b;
    scanf("%d, %d", &a, &b);
    printf("%d, %d", a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

I entered 5 9 as inputs, but I got 5 and 16 as outputs.

Comment: Always check `scanf`'s return value.

Comment: Your format string `"%d, %d"` tells `scanf` to expect an integer, a comma, and an integer.  When you run the program, are you typing a comma between `5` and `9`?

Comment: But can you bit explain more about what happened, Why did I get 5 and 16?

Comment: If you check the return value of `scanf`, you'll find that it returned 1, indicating that it was only able to read 1 of the two values you requested.  16 was simply a random value which the uninitialized variable `b` happened to start out with.  If you change the declaration to something like `int a = 77, b = 88;` you'll be able to see what's going on more clearly.

Comment: Can you please explain why C is putting random values as the default values for the uninitialized variables? In java, there are predefined default values like 0, and null. false, etc.

Comment: C is a language that compiles down to assembly the operating system can execute.  So "C" isn't "putting" or doing anything else once the program is complied.  And yes, Java (which does have a runtime component, the JVM) explicitly initializes variables to a zero value, but C does not define that as part of the implementation of the language.

Comment: @Damika C is not Java. In C, [static-duration variables are guaranteed to be initialized to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51329671/difference-between-static-global-variable-and-non-static-global-variable-in-c/51329933#51329933), because its cheap and easy for the compiler to arrange it, but "automatic" (i.e. local) variables are not, because there would be a significant run-time cost, incurred on every call, to do so. C's thinking is, if you want that initialization, you have to ask for it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the value of `scanf()` otherwise some or all the values you attempt to use are undefined.  In your case the input you provided did not match the `scanf()` format string.  I changed the format string to match the input you provided, removed headers that are not used and added a newline to your `printf()` statement:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a, b;
    if(scanf("%d%d", &a, &b) != 2) {
        printf("scanf failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("%d, %d\n", a, b);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use comma (,) to separate 2 inputs in `scanf()` function. This function automatically separates your inputs by number of occurrences of format specifiers i.e. `%d` in your case. However you have to separate variable addresses using comma.
Just use it like `scanf("%d %d", &a, &b)`.